# Boolean method return is not considered in the if statement

Tags: java, if-statement, boolean

An object has a name attribute of type String and a dependency attribute of the same type of the object itself. Now if I create an instance of the object and set the same instance as the dependency attribute, then checking if the object is reflexive by comparing its name with the dependencies name does not work in the if statement.

```
class Job {

    private String name;
    private Job dependency;

    boolean hasDependency() {
        return dependency != null;
    }

    //getter,setters
}
```

&

```
class JobSequence {

    private ArrayList<Job> jobsArrayList;
    private ArrayList<Job> orderedJobsArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

    JobSequence(ArrayList<Job> jobsArrayList) {
        this.jobsArrayList = jobsArrayList;
    }

    void sortByDependency() {
        for (Job job : jobsArrayList) {
            if (!orderedJobsArrayList.contains(job)) orderedJobsArrayList.add(job);

            if (job.hasDependency()) {
                if (!isReflexive(job, job.getDependency())) {
                    if (!orderedJobsArrayList.contains(job.getDependency())) {
                        int index = orderedJobsArrayList.indexOf(job);
                        orderedJobsArrayList.set(index, job.getDependency());
                        orderedJobsArrayList.add(index + 1, job);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private boolean isReflexive(Job i, Job j) {
        return i.getName().equals(j.getName());
    }
}
```

&

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Job a = new Job("a");
        Job b = new Job("b");
        Job c = new Job("c");

        a.setDependency(null);
        b.setDependency(null);
        c.setDependency(c);

        ArrayList<Job> jobArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        Collections.addAll(jobArrayList, a, b, c);

        JobSequence sequence = new JobSequence(jobArrayList);
        sequence.sortByDependency();
        sequence.getOrderedJobsArrayList().forEach(p -> System.out.println(p.getName()));
    }
}
```

> Result should be **a,b** NOT **a,b,c**

Comment: You add three jobs, so why should there be less? See if (!orderedJobsArrayList.contains(job)) orderedJobsArrayList.add(job);

Comment: We are talking about the first if statement in your foreach loop. (method sortByDependency)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `a` and `b` since they have no dependency, `hasDependency()` call returns `false`, hence they are just added to the `orderedJobsArrayList`

For `c`, you have the dependency as itself again `c`, from the first `if` check, it is also added to the list, since the list does not contain a `Job` with name `"c"` and with a dependency variable, then the `isReflexive(job, job.getDependency())` call returns a `true`, since `c.getName().equals(c.getName()) == true`, but your `if` condition has a negation of the return value, thus it is not continued to the bottom part of the algorithm.

Result of `a, b, c` in the `orderedJobsArrayList` is correct.

Answer (score 0):

You are adding all the jobs to the ordered list regardless of any of the dependency conditions:
`if (!orderedJobsArrayList.contains(job)) orderedJobsArrayList.add(job);`

Have you used a debugger to see that it passes the IsReflexive test?  In fact, you would get `a, b, c, c` if it were not.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

class JobSequence {
    private ArrayList<Job> jobsArrayList;
    private ArrayList<Job> orderedJobsArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

    JobSequence(ArrayList<Job> jobsArrayList) {
        this.jobsArrayList = jobsArrayList;
    }

    void sortByDependency() {
        for (Job job : jobsArrayList) {
            if (!orderedJobsArrayList.contains(job)) orderedJobsArrayList.add(job);

            if (job.hasDependency()) {
                if (!isReflexive(job, job.getDependency())) {
                    if (!orderedJobsArrayList.contains(job.getDependency())) {
                        int index = orderedJobsArrayList.indexOf(job);
                        orderedJobsArrayList.set(index, job.getDependency());
                        orderedJobsArrayList.add(index + 1, job);
                    }
                }else {
                    orderedJobsArrayList.remove(job);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private boolean isReflexive(Job i, Job j) {
        return i.getName().equals(j.getName());
    }

    public ArrayList<Job> getOrderedJobsArrayList() {
        return orderedJobsArrayList;
    }

    public void setOrderedJobsArrayList(ArrayList<Job> orderedJobsArrayList) {
        this.orderedJobsArrayList = orderedJobsArrayList;
    }
}

Try this-
```

As per your implementation the output a,b,c is perfect as you have added all the job in the list i.e.

**if (!orderedJobsArrayList.contains(job)) orderedJobsArrayList.add(job);**

The condition **if(!isReflexive(job, job.getDependency()))** evaluates to false in case of job **c** so you should remove that job from the list.

Comment: I checked for a job being reflexive initially before adding it to the list. That solved my problem. Your way is sound too.